# Using some stop words to filter another list of paths

Tags: python

I have a bunch of paths where I'd like to filter them to only specific directories that I need.

```
exclusions = ['venv_windows', 'venv_bash', 'targets']

paths = \
    [r'C:\Users\User\Documents\project\module',
     r'C:\Users\User\Documents\project\module\app.py',
     r'C:\Users\User\Documents\project\venv_bash',
     r'C:\Users\User\Documents\project\venv_windows',
     r'C:\Users\User\Documents\project\targets']

reduced = list(filter(lambda w: w not in exclusions, paths))
print(str(reduced))
```

However for some reason this returns all items. I would like to just return paths that don't have venv_bash, venv_windows or targets within the path itself.

Comment: Using `in` will only work if you check if a substring appears within a string. Here you are checking for example if `'C:\Users\User\Documents\project\venv_bash'` is in `['venv_windows', 'venv_bash', 'targets']`. And it isn't. If you check if the substring `venv_bash` is within `['venv_windows', 'venv_bash', 'targets']` you'll get True. Work from there.

Comment: FYI only: `print(reduced)` prints the same as `print(str(reduced))` because a list *already* gets converted to a string before it can be printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code checks if one of your path is not in exclusions. For example, you check if `'C:\Users\User\Documents\project\module' is not in exclusions`.
Of course it is not.

Instead you want to check if any exclusion is in your path.
For example you can do:

```
reduced = [p for p in paths if all(e not in p for e in exclusions)]
```

Which gives:

```
['C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\project\\module', 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\project\\module\\app.py']
```

Comment: No need to create a list to put inside `all`. In fact, `all` will short-circuit as soon as *any* of those tests fail `:)` (As I have been told; and now I pass it on.)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm just having one of those days. I like your list comp though very nice!

Answer (score 0):

You're testing whether each of the entire paths is in the `exclusions` list, which it never is. You need to make your function a bit more elaborate and test if any of the parts are in your exclusions list. Something like the following might work

```
def exclude_path(path, exclusions):
    for part in path.split('\\'):
        if part in exclusions:
            return True

    return False
```